# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null- at Object.addListitem, at ctrlAddItem, at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am getting this error- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null- at Object.addListitem, at ctrlAddItem, at HTMLDocument",while inserting my data to the UI of my calculator app.
I am just a beginner and not able to understand the bug.
Please help me find my mistake.
Here are my HTML and JavaScript codes.

HTML code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&family=Recursive&family=Rowdies:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\stylesheet\main.css">
        <title>BUDGETOFY</title>
    </head>
<body class="container">
<div class="background">

    <div class="av-budget-heading">Available Budget:</div>
    <div class="av-budget">+2,500</div>
    <div class="income">
        <div class="inex-heading left">Income</div>
        <div class="inex-number little-right-1">+3,500</div>
    </div>

    <div class="expense">
        <div class="inex-heading left">Expenses</div>
        <div class="inex-number little-right-2">-1,000</div>
        <div class="ex-percent right percent-main">28%</div>
    </div>
    
    
</div>
   <hr> 
<div class="selections">

    <select class="drop-down add-type">
        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
        <option value="exp">-</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" class="drop-down add-description" placeholder="Add Description">
    <input type="number" class="drop-down add-value" placeholder="Value">
    <button id="button"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline ok-btn"></i></button>
</div>

   <hr>

<div class="wrapper line">

    <div class="income-down">
        <h2 class="in">INCOME</h2>

    <!--
    <div class="income-list">
        <div class="allinc" id="income-0">
            <div class="add-income inc-left">salary</div>
            <div class="income-amt inc-amt">+2,000</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
 
        <div class="allinc" id="income-1">
            <div class="add-income inc-left">sold car</div>
            <div class="income-amt inc-amt">+1,500</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
    </div>
    

    <div class="expense-down">
        <h2 class="ex">EXPENSES</h2>

    <!--
    <div class="expense-list">
        <div class="allexp" id="expense-0">
            <div class="add-expense exp-left">rent</div>
            <div class="expense-amt exp-amt">-900</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="allexp" id="expense-1">
            <div class="add-expense exp-left">grocery</div>
            <div class="expense-amt exp-amt">-100</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
    </div>
    
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code-

```
//BUDGET CONTROLLER

var budgetController = (function(){

    var Expense = function(id, description, value){
        this.id = id;
        this.decription = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var Income = function(id, description, value){
        this.id = id;
        this.decription = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var data = {
        allItems : {
            exp: [],
            inc: []
        },

        total : {
            exp: 0,
            inc: 0
        }
    };
 
    return {
        addItems: function(type, des, val){
            var newItem, ID;

            if(data.allItems[type].length > 0){
                ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
            }else {
                ID = 0;
            }
            
            
            if(type === 'exp'){
                newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
            }else if(type === 'inc'){
                newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
            }
        
        data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
        return newItem;
        },
        
        //testing purpose
        testing: function(){
            console.log(data);
        }
    };

})();


//UI CONTROLLER

var UIController = (function(){

    var DOMstrings = {
        inputType: '.add-type',
        inputDescription: '.add-description',
        inputValue: '.add-value',
        inputButton: 'button',
        incomeContainer: '.income-list',
        expensesContainer: '.expense-list',
    };

    return {

        getInput: function(){
            return{
                type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // inc or exp
                decription: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
                value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
            };
        },

        addListitem: function(obj, type){
            var html, newHtml, element;
            
            //create HTML string with placeholder text

            if(type === 'inc'){

                element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;

                html = '<div class="allinc" id="income-%id%"><div class="add-income inc-left">%description%</div><div class="income-amt inc-amt">%value%</div><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';
            }else if(type === 'exp'){

                element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

                '<div class="allexp" id="expense-%id%"><div class="add-expense exp-left">%description%</div><div class="expense-amt exp-amt">%value%</div><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';
            }
            
            //replace placeholder text with some actual data  
            
            newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.decription);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);

            //insert the HTML into DOM

            document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);

        },

        getDOMstrings: function(){
            return DOMstrings;
        }
    };
})();


//CONTROLLER

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl){

    var setupEventListeners = function(){

        var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

        document.getElementById(DOM.inputButton).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
        
            if(event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){
            ctrlAddItem();
        }
      });
    };

        var ctrlAddItem = function(){
            var input, newItem;

        //get the field input data
            input = UICtrl.getInput();

        //add the item to the budget controller
            newItem = budgetCtrl.addItems(input.type, input.description, input.value);

        //add the item to UI
            UICtrl.addListitem(newItem, input.type);

        //calculate the budget

        //display budget on UI

        };

        return {

            init: function(){

                //testing purpose
                console.log('hello');
                setupEventListeners();
            }
        };
})(budgetController,UIController);

controller.init();
```

Comment: Return value of `document.querySelector`: _An HTMLElement object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or null is returned if there are no matches._

Comment: Sorry sir, but i did not get that @RobMoll

Comment: Looks like you are attempting this CSS selector `.income-list` but have this div `<div class="income-list">....</div>` commented

Comment: yeah i corrected that. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy solution.
you are definding element as 'income-list' and then adjacent HTML to its:

```
if(type === 'inc'){

    element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;
...

}else if(type === 'exp'){

    element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

...

document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
```

which is good.. but look in your HTML. income-list is disable:

```
 <!--
    <div class="income-list">
        <div class="allinc" id="income-0">
            <div class="add-income inc-left">salary</div>
            <div class="income-amt inc-amt">+2,000</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
 
        <div class="allinc" id="income-1">
            <div class="add-income inc-left">sold car</div>
            <div class="income-amt inc-amt">+1,500</div>
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
```

what you should do is to delete the  around the HTML with the elements you want to implement HTML from the js file.

also you will need to do the same for the '.expense-list' in the HTML

Its from Jonas Schmedtmann course in udemy. very good course. i took it as well . i can suggest you to notice the details and follow step by step and code with him together. good luck.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, it solved the problem. Yes i am doing Jonas Schmedtmann course in udemy. THANKS! @elnatan vazana

Comment: Im glad I helped you, Best regards and good luck in your code journey.